# Search when clicking an image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site where users can search a directory of sports camps based on country, price, season and organiser. Looks like this:

[image: Search]

When users click search I 'get' the search page and add the params in the URL, which then renders a list of sport camps matching the search params. This works flawlessly. The URL looks something like this: 
`"localhost:3000/camps?utf8=✓&country=Spain&organiser=Brett&season=Summer&price=5000&commit=Search"`

Further down the page I have a list of images with most popular countries e.g. "Spain". My question is this:

How do I add a link to the image that would then search for all camps with country = Spain?

Model:

```
class Camp < ApplicationRecord
  def self.search(country, price, organiser, season)
    where("country LIKE ? AND price < ? AND organiser LIKE ? AND season LIKE ?", country, price, organiser, season)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def search
  country = params[:country]
  price = params[:price]
  organiser = params[:organiser]
  season = params[:season]

  if country.blank?
    country = '%'
  end

  if season.blank?
    season = '%'
  end

  if organiser.blank?
    organiser = '%'
  end

  @camps = Camp.search(country, price, organiser, season)
end
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= link_to image_tag("cardheader.png") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `link_to` like this,

```
<%= link_to your_method_path(:country => "spain") do %>
  <%= image_tag('spain.png') %>
<% end %>
```

**you can use the dynamic image and the country name to pass to the method**

Here is your method(taking from one of the comments below):

```
def search
  country = params[:country].present? ? params[:country] : '%'
  price = params[:price].present? ? params[:price] : '%'
  organiser = params[:organiser].present? ? params[:organiser] : '%'
  season = params[:season].present? ? params[:season] : '%'

  @camps = Camp.search(country, price, organiser, season)
end
```

[**Here is the reference to it**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: Thx for your reply. When doing it like this my URL becomes: [http://localhost:3000/camps?country=spain] when it should ideally be something like [/camps?utf8=✓&country=Spain&organiser=&season=&price=&commit=Search]

Doing it like this doesn't render any results.

Comment: so you need all the remaining parameters also while sending?

Comment: Seems like that's the case yes. Alternatively I could make a new controller and a new function in the model with the specific country searches.

Comment: yes, if you want the search per country you can create a new method.

Comment: Ideally I would like it to use the same method with country as the only param and the other params empty?

Comment: I think the method you have may work for you, check `season.present?`

Comment: You can easily use the same method, it just needs a bit cleaning up. 
`country = params[:country] || '%'`

Comment: @Andy, Iceman  has a good point there, added that syntax in my answer. please check.

Comment: Thanks for your time and replies guys - it works now. When I change to your suggestion Iceman it breaks:  | | '%'.

Comment: breaks in what way?

Comment: breaks by saying what?

Comment: Ahh, you probably want `country = params[:country].present ? params[:country] : '%'`. I'm used to having my params as `nil` but you seem to send them in as blanks

Comment: that may be the case too.

Comment: @Andy, please check the answer now and you can accept it, if you find it useful.

Comment: Thx guys thats awesome